# 'composer identity issue ...' does not give any output

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have created an angular application using composer and yeoman where transactions are happening correctly. Now I want to add users with different operational roles. I have added details in the permission file and created participants accordingly.

percmissions.acl looks like:

```
rule Govt {
    description: "Allow all participants access to all resources"
    participant: "org.acme.<network-name>.Govt"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.acme.<network-name>.*"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule Farmer {
    description: "Allow all participants access to all resources"
    participant: "org.acme.<network-name>.Farmer"
    operation: READ
    resource: "org.acme.<network-name>.*"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule SystemACL {
  description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
  participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
  operation: ALL
  resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
  action: ALLOW  
}
```

Participants 'govt1' and 'farmer1' are successfully added as suggested in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/managing/participant-add.html

To issue identity, I run the command:

```
composer identity issue -p hlfv1 -n ‘<networkname>’ -i admin -s adminpw -u govt1id1 -a "resource:org.acme.cphnetwork.Govt#govt1”
```

The issue is that the command does not give any output.. neither success nor error.

Comment: could you issue the command 'export DEBUG=composer:*' and try the command again to see what is output ? It will also create a file in the logs directory which should contain more information to what is output.

Comment: coder_ajay - per our Rocketchat (1 day after your original post) - you should get your Composer environment (at time of writing it was v0.11.1) in synch with the GA editions of a runtime Fabric environment (where you had RC1 editions). Your command is perfectly legitimate and syntactically correct, more likely something was right with your Fabric.

Comment: Yes, as discussed on Rocketchat; I followed below steps to upgrade the version correctly. 1st, remove all the existing images. 2nd, delete all files and folder from '.composer-connection-profiles' and '.composer-credentials' folders. 3rd, uninstall and install 'composer-cli', 'generator-hyperledger-composer', 'composer-rest-server'. 4th, download and unzip the latest fabric tools, start the fabric and create a new composer profile. 5th, 'npm install' in the application directory. Regarding the participants, I will update here soon.

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony: The issue mentioned in this question persists.  `composer participant add...` - participant is created and listed in `composer network list...`. But `composer identity issue...` command don't return anything. Its mentioned in the documentation that _ the **issuer** of an identity must itself have issuer authority_ . How to assign issuer authority to a participant using CLI? Whats the use of rule 'SystemACL'? I added participants by running `composer-playground` (localhost:8080) from same application directory, but these participants don't get listed in REST API (3000/explorer).

Comment: on q1. You can use the `--issuer, -x` flag on `composer identity issue`  command to create an identity (associated with a participant) that will also have 'issuer' authority -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/composer.identity.issue.html  on q2. Your playground would need to be connected via a v1 connection profile (and then you would need to connect to that deployed business network in playground) to the same runtime fabric where you originally deployed your business network (which your REST APIs are consuming via rest-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the original question, as per discussion on rocketchat:

Original command:

```
composer identity issue -p hlfv1 -n ‘<networkname>’ -i admin -s adminpw -u govt1id1 -a "resource:org.acme.cphnetwork.Govt#govt1”
```

Solution:

1. Remove the 'single quotes' from the `<networkname>`
2. Remove the word 'resource:'
3. Remove "double quotes" from namespace#participant

So if the business network name is govt-application, the command should look like:

```
composer identity issue -p hlfv1 -n govt-application -i admin -s adminpw -u govt1id1 -a org.acme.cphnetwork.Govt#govt1
```

As per discussion on rocketchat, simply removing the word 'resouce:' and retaining the quotes also works.

Answer (score 0):

on q1. You can use the `--issuer, -x` flag on `composer identity issue` command to create an identity (associated with a participant) that will also have 'issuer' authority -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/composer.identity.issue.html … on q2. Your playground would need to be connected via a v1 connection profile (and then you would need to connect to that deployed business network in playground) to the same runtime fabric where you originally deployed your business network (which your REST APIs are consuming via rest-server)